# How to get access token using gmail api - Java, spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-api

Trying to implement `OAuth2` using Spring Boot and Google apis. I am trying to get access token from Google apis. This is code I have so far:

**application.yml**

```
gmail:
  credentials:
    secret: xxxxxxx
  clientid: xxxxxxxx
  auth-server-url: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
  scope: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile
```

**RegistrationServiceImpl.java**

```
@Component
public class GmailServiceImpl implements GmailService {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RegistrationController.class);

    @Value("${gmail.credentials.secret}")
    private String SECRETKEY;

    @Value("${gmail.clientid}")
    private String CLIENTID;

    @Value("${gmail.auth-server-url}")
    private String AUTHURL;

    @Value("${gmail.scope}")
    private String SCOPE;

    private String redirect_uri = "http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/registerapirealm/broker/google/endpoint";

    @Autowired
    RestTemplate restTemplate;


    @Override
    public AuthCode getAuthCode() {
        AuthCode responseToken = null;
        try {

            MultiValueMap<String, String> urlParameters = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
            urlParameters.add("scope", SCOPE);
            urlParameters.add("redirect_uri", redirect_uri);
            urlParameters.add("response_type", "code");
            urlParameters.add("access_type", "offline");
            urlParameters.add("state", "state_parameter_passthrough_value");
            urlParameters.add("client_id", CLIENTID);

            responseToken = getGoogleAuthCode(urlParameters);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return responseToken;

    }

    private AuthCode getGoogleAuthCode(MultiValueMap<String, String> urlParameters) {

        AuthCode authCode = new AuthCode();

        String uri = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth";

        HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        httpHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);
        HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>> request = new HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>>(urlParameters, httpHeaders);

        ResponseEntity<String> result = restTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.POST, request, String.class);
        log.info("{}", result);
        log.info("{}", result.getBody());

        String responseCode= result.getBody();

        if (responseCode != null) {
            authCode.setAuthCode(responseCode);

        } else {
            return null;
        }

        return authCode;
    }
```

**AuthCode.java**

```
@Data
public class AuthCode {

    private String authCode;
}
```

I am getting the next response in Postman:

```
{
    "authCode": "<!DOCTYPE html><head><title>Omdirigerar</title></head><body bgcolor=\"#ffffff\" text=\"#000000\" link=\"#0000cc\" vlink=\"#551a8b\" alink=\"#ff0000\"><form jsname=\"RimvDb\" action=\"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?trampoline=1&amp;as=S-1442069211%3A1631459280968786\" method=\"POST\"><input type=\"hidden\" name=\"access_type\" value=\"offline\"><input type=\"hidden\" name=\"scope\" value=\"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile\"><input type=\"hidden\" name=\"response_type\" value=\"code\"><input type=\"hidden\" name=\"redirect_uri\" value=\"http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/registerapirealm/broker/google/endpoint\"><input type=\"hidden\" name=\"state\" value=\"state_parameter_passthrough_value\"><input type=\"hidden\" name=\"client_id\" value=\"869675774281-68fa1n67en55nsov2hgbobmdm9sue00u.apps.googleusercontent.com\"></form><script nonce=\"kvN9vMtl0FIXHmh+Uxp+ww\">document.forms[0].submit();</script></body>"
}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Does this help --> https://community.postman.com/t/postman-google-oauth2-0-missing-required-parameter-code/8207 ?

Comment: You should not share your client id  and client secret please remember to go and reset the secret on your project as you just shared it with the internet.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly, you are using the grant_type `authorization_code` which mean that you've to provide the code (authorization code) while making the request. Basically, the application will exchange code for an access token.

> code (required) This parameter is the authorization code that the
> client previously received from the authorization server.

To begin with the authorization flow, the first step is to obtained the code from authorization server. Example:

```
https://{authorization_server_endpoint}
 ?client_id=xxxxx
 &redirect_uri={the url on which you want authorization server to redirect with the code}
 &scope=xxxxx
 &state=xxxxx
 &response_type=code
```

You can now use the code obtained from above step in the following call for exchange with the access token.

```
POST /oauth/token
Host: {authorization server}
 
grant_type=authorization_code
&code=xxxxxxxxxxx
&redirect_uri={the redirect url used in step one}
&client_id=xxxxxxxxxx
&client_secret=xxxxxxxxxx
```

For google authorization server you can check with the following documentation.
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#httprest

Comment: Thank you Harry but can you show it with code? I am aware that I have to go with GET method to get code and then send it with POST method. But what do I need to send with GET method to get code?

Comment: I've updated the answer and also linked the google authorization server documentation.